# XML XSLT Transform to XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT stylesheet that transforms an XML file to JSON format and a part of the schema for the XML allow any XML what-so-ever, which I need to just encode as a string in the corresponding JSON.

I have the elements getting created OK I am just having trouble getting the namespaces to behave correctly.

The problem is that every single namespace in scope of the current element is being output for every single element. I only want to output namespaces as they are first declared in the original XML.

This is what I am currently trying to do, I have tried a few things and cannot figure out a way to do what I need.

I call a template that is responsible for transforming attributes for the current node with:

```
<xsl:call-template name="elementAttributes">
        <xsl:with-param name="element" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

With the following template:

```
<xsl:template name="elementAttributes">
        <xsl:param name="element"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$element/namespace::*">
            <!--dont include default namespace-->
            <xsl:if test="boolean(name())">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                <xsl:text>='</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

So for instance with the XML:

```
<valueString>
        <dms:animal xmlns:dms="http://test.net/2012/dms/">
            <dms:dog>woof</dms:dog>
            <dms:cat>meow</dms:cat>
            <reptile:crocodile xmlns:reptile="http://reptile.test.net/2012/dms/"></reptile:crocodile>
        </dms:animal>
</valueString>
```

I am ending up with:

```
<dms:animal dcds='http://purl.org/dc/xmlns/2008/09/01/dc-ds-xml/' dms='http://test.net/2012/dms/' ns0='http://purl.org/dc/xmlns/2008/09/01/dc-ds-xml/' xml='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'>
<dms:dog dcds='http://purl.org/dc/xmlns/2008/09/01/dc-ds-xml/' dms='http://test.net/2012/dms/' ns0='http://purl.org/dc/xmlns/2008/09/01/dc-ds-xml/' xml='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'>woof</dms:dog>
<dms:cat dcds='http://purl.org/dc/xmlns/2008/09/01/dc-ds-xml/' dms='http://test.net/2012/dms/' ns0='http://purl.org/dc/xmlns/2008/09/01/dc-ds-xml/' xml='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'>meow</dms:cat>
<reptile:crocodile dcds='http://purl.org/dc/xmlns/2008/09/01/dc-ds-xml/' dms='http://test.net/2012/dms/' ns0='http://purl.org/dc/xmlns/2008/09/01/dc-ds-xml/' reptile='http://reptile.test.net/2012/dms/' xml='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'/>
```

when I only basically want to get back the same XML.

I know it is possible to do copy-of to easily copy XML to an output but I since I am outputting the results as text due to the JSON format I could not get it to work that way, as only the text nodes would be copied and not the XML structure.

Comment: Michael Kay is right. Do have a look at the code of my XPath Visualizer to see how this is done: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that what you are trying to do is a pretty weird design. All my instincts are to go back to the requirements stage and look at whether a different design would make more sense.

However, if you really want to do what you are trying to do, you will have to examine each namespace and output it only if the namespace is in scope for this element and not for the parent element.